# gvfsd: Error creating server at address: Too many open files

Tags: 19.04, gvfs

I'm getting hundreds of errors like this recently:

```
Jan 20 13:21:01 server2 gvfsd[4093]: daemon: Error creating server at address 
  unix:abstract=/dbus-vfs-daemon/socket-jOhPfYdB: 
  Unable to create socket: Too many open files
```

I've checked the open file handles, nothing seemed particularly offensive. Raised limits anyway, makes no difference. Goes away for a while after reboot but always starts up again before long.

Perhaps related, often I can't browse trash can using the file manager. (I'm using PCManFM). It pops up a dialog saying "too many open files." If I kill `gvfsd-trash` it might start working again. The errors still keep appearing in the log even while trash can is working, though.

I'm completely current on eoan. This is a fairly recent occurrence but I can't tie it to any specific update or software install.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and I found that open files != file descriptors.

For me `lsof` reports like 600,000 files, half of them gecko (firefox). Closing firefox reduces them to 150,000 but does not change anything regarding gvfsd unable to open sockets.

Now, if you issue a command like this:

```
ls -1 /proc | \
grep \[0-9\]| \
sed "s,.*,printf 'process %10d uses file descriptors: ' &  ;sudo ls -l /proc/&/fd | wc -l," | \
bash | \
sort -h -r -k 6 | \
head
```

*I am not a linux scripting pro, so this is far from perfect*

*This command is supposed to count the FD for any PID currently running*

You will see that most processes use maximum 50. Only `gvfsd` is at the max 1024 set by `ulimit`. so maybe raising ulimit fixes the problem. maybe not ;)

`gvfsd` is a user process and the user is allowed to set the ulimit to max `ulimit -Hn`. So raising the limit temporary is as easy as issuing `ulimit -n 2048`. But this only affects the current shell. You have to add it to `~/.bashrc`. **EDIT: doesn't work. Where the hell do I define the ulimit for gvfsd?**

ps. I do not have the 100% CPU problem, except when there is a file on disk that is constantly changing (eg. downloading larger files like movies). No idea if this is related.